# String graph with girth 5 and min degree 4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am currently doing research on string graphs. A graph $G = (V,E)$ with vertices $V = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is called a string graph if there exists a representation of the vertices as continuous curves in the plane $\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\}$ such that $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j$ intersect if and only if $i$ and $j$ are connected in $G$, i.e., $ij \in E$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_graph.

In particular, I am searching for a string graph in which every vertex has degree at least 4 and in which the length of the shortest cycle (girth) is at least 5, or for a proof that such a graph does not exist. Note that the Robertson graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson_graph) does have the right minimum degree and girth, but so far I have been unable to prove whether this is a string graph or not.

Does anyone have a clue as to what such a graph should look like or why it would be impossible to make one? I have tried using the crossing number inequality or an application of Kuratowski's Theorem to show that a string representation of such a graph cannot be made to work, but so far to no avail. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are some results in this direction, but it looks like this is still an open problem.

For circle graphs, this bound is just barely false. The Wikipedia page on [circle graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_graph) has a beautiful diagram of a circle graph with girth $4$ and minimum degree $5$. On the other hand, [Ageev (1999)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98001927) shows that any circle graph with girth $5$ has minimum degree $3$ or less.

For general string graphs, there is a surprising connection to cops-and-robbers games. [Gavenčiak et al. (2015)](http://gavento.ucw.cz/papers/Gavenciak,%20Jelinek,%20Klavik,%20Kratochvil%20-%20Cops%20and%20Robbers%20on%20String%20Graphs.pdf) show that the maximum cop number of a string graph is between $3$ and $15$, and observe that this implies that no string graph can have girth $5$ and minimum degree $16$: on any such graph, the robber always has at least $16$ escape routes, and no cop can block two of them, so $15$ cops cannot block all of them.

At the very least, this implies that there's no easy construction of a string graph with girth $5$ and minimum degree $4$ that the authors of that paper could find: the same argument would show that it is a string graph with cop number $4$, improving their lower bound. (As it is, I think their lower bound comes from planar graphs, which are known to have maximum cop number $3$.)